# How to initialize a GMP mpz_t with an integer

Tags: c++, gmp

I want to initialize a `mpz_t` from GMP with an integer (e.g. 2). I've tried the following variants:

```
mpz_t n(2); // Compiler error
mpz_t n = 2; // Compiler error
```

What is the correct way of initializing the `mpz_t` to 2?

Comment: I think you are looking for the type `mpz_class` (from gmpxx.h), not the low-level C mpz_t type.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, it would be easier using that. However `gmpxx` is a separate package to install and I wanted to do a problem-solution post on the raw `mpz_t` because some people are likely to run into that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [GMP documentation on initializing integers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html) and the [GMP documentation on combined initialization and set](https://gmplib.org/manual/Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign.html):

```
mpz_t n;
mpz_init_set_ui(n); // ui means unsigned int. Use si for signed values.
```

Thanks to [Mark Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse) for mentioning combined init & set.

Comment: You can also merge the last 2 lines.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, I wasn't aware of that actually ;-)  I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: The `mpz_init_set_ui(n);` needs to be, for example, `mpz_init_set_ui(n, 0);`.